# How to Post xml data in c# with XmlElementAttribute Class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, api, post

hi everyone i'm have some xml data like this to post on httpPost

```
<logindetail>
<player account="IDR" country="IN" firstName="" lastName="" userName=""
nickName="" tester="1" partnerId="LION8" commonWallet="0"></player>
<partners>
<partner partnerId="" partnerType="0" />
<partner partnerId="" partnerType="1" />
<partner partnerId="" partnerType="1" />
</partners>
</logindetail>
```

and my code for post the request is like this on c#

```
string reqBody = xmlData;

var result = HttpPost(ApiUrl, xmlData, "text/xml");
```

how i can set the xml data as reqBody for post it on httpPost

Comment: Do you want to get implementation of HttpPost method?

Comment: yes i want get implementation on httpPost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simle code for Http Post request using HttpClient:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

    async Task<string> HttpPostAsync(string url, string data , string mediaType)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage();

                request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);

                request.Content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType);
                var responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                return await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

        }
```

Examle of using:

```
var xmlData = @"<logindetail>
<player account=""IDR"" country=""IN"" firstName="""" lastName="""" userName=""""
nickName="""" tester=""1"" partnerId=""LION8"" commonWallet=""0""></player>
<partners>
<partner partnerId="""" partnerType=""0"" />
<partner partnerId="""" partnerType=""1"" />
<partner partnerId="""" partnerType=""1"" />
</partners>
</logindetail>";

var response = await HttpPostAsync("https://httpbin.org/post", xmlData, "Text/xml");
```

Comment: how i can set the xmldata with my example i write above ?

Comment: you can set it in local variable or read from file `var xmlData = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("test.xml");`